# set timeout for a WebSphere Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, jax-rs, websphere

i'm using a spring boot application which running on a LibertyCode server,

I have a web server configured with a timeout :

```
ClientConfig configuration = new ClientConfig();
        configuration.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, connecTimeout);
        configuration.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, readTimeout);
        apiClient = ClientBuilder.newClient(configuration);
        WebTarget target = apiClient.target(uri);
        Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).header("accept", "application/json")
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json").get();
```

it works perfectly on my local machine ( based on tomcat without websphere)
but when i run the war on a WebSphere server the timeout was **ignored** !
that's the features using in my **server.xml** :

```
   <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>restConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>beanValidation-1.1</feature>
        <feature>adminCenter-1.0</feature>
        <feature>transportSecurity-1.0</feature>
```

Any help please

Comment: Do you mean timeout occurred at lower value, higher value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try changing `<feature>restConnector-1.0</feature>` to `<feature>restConnector-2.0</feature>`?  I think that the 1.0 connector leaks JAX-RS - basically including it for the application - even if you package your own version of JAX-RS and CXF, etc.  When that happens you get Liberty's version of JAX-RS (which is based on CXF but doesn't allow users to load the CXF-specific implementation classes) for the APIs and possibly even some implementation classes.  Further, I think the restConnector-1.0 feature uses an older version of JAX-RS that may not support the connect and read timeouts.

If moving to restConnector-2.0 doesn't work, then I would suggest explicitly adding the `jaxrs-2.1` feature and then using the JAX-RS APIs instead of the implementation-specific APIs.  It would look something like:

```
Client apiClient = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                                .connectTimeout(connecTimeout)
                                .readTimeout(readTimeout)
                                .build();
WebTarget target = apiClient.target(uri);
Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                          .header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                          .get();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: is that normal that got "javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure" after changing the feature, call to an external API ?

Comment: No, that sounds like an error in the SSL layer. It could be that the server uses an unfamiliar certificate or something like that.  Liberty allows you to specify your own SSL key and trust stores. I’d say to check the Liberty SSL docs and then post a new question if you are still seeing the problem.